# golang の IDE には何がある?

Tags: go

golang で開発を始めようと思いました。以下の条件を見たす IDE には何がありますか?

- 無料で利用できる。
- ブレークポイントの設定やステップ実行などの、debug 実行ができる。

Comment: ちょっと前までIntelliJのGoプラグインがタダだったのですけどね。Golandと言う製品版が出た時に、プラグインは使えなくなったみたいです。デバッガの使いやすさはピカイチです。IntelliJ, PyCharmの使用経験があれば、同じ感覚で使えます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vscode で諸々のプラグインを入れることで、無料かつデバッグ実行を実現できました。

Answer (score 0):

LiteIDEというのがありますよー。 http://liteide.org/en/